# Process and store Azure IoT Hub messages in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have started learning about the possibilities brought by Microsoft Azure IoT Hub. It seems really promising, but I see a major flaw in the inability to process the messages passing through the Hub. I would like to intercept the messages sent to the Hub, do some business logic, store them in Azure database and then send them to their recipients.

However, I cannot find any evidence or guides, if and how this is possible. I have considered using SignalR (with which I have quite positive experience), but not many IoT devices support SignalR client. So, is there a reliable way (either regular, or workaround) to process the IoT Hub messages and store them in Azure database?

Comment: Actually, the exact opposite is true. IoT Hub *adds* preconfigured templates for this on top of the functionalities *already* available with Event Hub. With Event Hub  you can use Stream Analytics for analysis, Event processors for custom processing, AMQP/MQTT for sending messages from devices to the hub. IoT Hub adds device management, deployment, etc. Azure IoT suite goes even farther and offers preconfigured templates for eg. remote monitoring, predictive maintenance

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for Azure IoT and Event Hub? What you ask is already available and part of the tutorials - it wouldn't be an IoT offering if you couldn't send events or process them on the server

Comment: I probably should change my source of knowledge, because from that I understood that IoT Hub serves just for message broadcasting and nothing more. Thank you for pointing out the Event processor - it seems just like the thing I need.

Comment: Did you check the [Azure IoT Learning Path](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/iot-hub/) in the docs?

Comment: No, not at all. I had just some material from the school and then started googling random topics - which was not the best idea, as it seems, since I completely misunderstood the whole platform.

Comment: I have studied the Azure platform. There are so many possibilities, it is really confusing. Just to clarify: if I want to process the IoT messages, store all of them in Azure DB and send the critical ones via a Duplex WCF, I will need an Azure DB (to store the data), IoT Hub (to send & receive messages), Storage Account & Service Bus (to queue the messages) and a custom implementation of Event Processor (which can be a part of the WCF project, storing data and sending messages). Am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104261/discussion-between-storm-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Answer (score 1):

You need to process the messages using Stream Analytics.  It's a SQL like language that let you query the message stream and send the results to various outputs like SQL Database, DocumentDB, PowerBI, Blob Storage.

Comment: Stream Analytics is of *analysis* of the messages. While you can use it to redirect messages to a database, it does incur additional cost. A simple event processor class is enough to store data to a table